# Binary Data Receive through Websocket

Tags: javascript, c#, html, websocket, tcplistener

I have web socket application in C# and other I have small html page that connect to my Web socket and then send the message it receives correctly on my Web socket C# application.

The problem comes when i try to send the image data. First I get the image data into base 64 string and then convert the string into Uint8Array through JavaScript and send that array buffer to my C# Websocket application.

The data length is same but when I try to convert the byte array that I have received from web browser to my C# application it does not properly convert into Base 64 string and get a proper image on my C# application.

Please see the code

Java Script side :

```
function StringToBinary(string) {
            var chars, code, i, isUCS2, len, _i;

            len = string.length;
            chars = [];
            isUCS2 = false;
            for (i = _i = 0; 0 <= len ? _i < len : _i > len; i = 0 <= len ? ++_i : --_i) {
                code = String.prototype.charCodeAt.call(string, i);
                if (code > 255) {
                    isUCS2 = true;
                    chars = null;
                    break;
                } else {
                    chars.push(code);
                }
            }
            if (isUCS2 === true) {
                return unescape(encodeURIComponent(string));
            } else {
                return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.apply(chars));
            }
        }
        function StringToUint8Array(string) {
            var binary, binLen, buffer, chars, i, _i;
            binary = StringToBinary(string);
            binLen = binary.length;
            buffer = new ArrayBuffer(binLen);
            chars = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            for (i = _i = 0; 0 <= binLen ? _i < binLen : _i > binLen; i = 0 <= binLen ? ++_i : --_i) {
                chars[i] = String.prototype.charCodeAt.call(binary, i);
            }
            return chars;
        }

 function StringToArrayBuffer(string) {
            return StringToUint8Array(string).buffer;
        }
//Canvas to get the Base64string
var data = ctx.toDataURL('image/png')
  var StringbinaryBuffer = StringToArrayBuffer(data);

webSocket.send(StringbinaryBuffer);
```

C# Code:

```
public static Frame FromBuffer(byte[] buffer)
        {
            var frame = new Frame();

            // If no extended payload length and no mask are used, the payload starts at the 3rd byte
            int payloadStartIndex = 2;

            var firstNibble = (byte)(buffer[0] & 0xF0);
            var secondNibble = (byte)(buffer[0] & 0x0F);

            // When the first bit of the first byte is set,
            // It means that the current frame is the final frame of a message
            if (firstNibble == Fin)
                frame.IsFin = true;

            //  The opcode consists of the last four bits in the first byte
            //frame.Opcode = (Opcodes)secondNibble;
            frame.Opcode = (Opcodes)secondNibble; ;

            // The last bit of the second byte is the masking bit
            bool isMasked = Convert.ToBoolean((buffer[1] & 0x80) >> 7);

            // Payload length is stored in the first seven bits of the second byte
            var payloadLength = (ulong)(buffer[1] & 0x7F);

            // From RFC-6455 - Section 5.2
            // "If 126, the following 2 bytes interpreted as a 16-bit unsigned integer are the payload length
            // (expressed in network byte order)"
            if (payloadLength == TwoBytesLengthCode)
            {
                Array.Reverse(buffer, payloadStartIndex, 2);
                payloadLength = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, payloadStartIndex);
                payloadStartIndex += 2;
            }

            // From RFC-6455 - Section 5.2
            // "If 127, the following 8 bytes interpreted as a 64-bit unsigned integer (the most significant bit MUST be 0) 
            // are the payload length (expressed in network byte order)"
            else if (payloadLength == EightBytesLengthCode)
            {
                Array.Reverse(buffer, payloadStartIndex, 8);
                payloadLength = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, payloadStartIndex);
                payloadStartIndex += 8;
            }

            frame.PayloadLength = payloadLength;

            // From RFC-6455 - Section 5.2
            // "All frames sent from the client to the server are masked by a
            // 32-bit value that is contained within the frame.  This field is
            // present if the mask bit is set to 1 and is absent if the mask bit
            // is set to 0."
            if (isMasked)
            {
                frame.MaskingKey = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, payloadStartIndex);
                payloadStartIndex += 4;
            }
            //buffer = new byte[(int)frame.PayloadLength + payloadStartIndex];
            var content = new byte[frame.PayloadLength];
            // Array.Copy(buffer, payloadStartIndex, content, 0, (int)frame.PayloadLength);

            if (isMasked)
                UnMask(content, frame.MaskingKey);

            frame.UnmaskedPayload = content;

            return frame;
        }
 private static void UnMask (byte[] payload, int maskingKey)
        {
            int currentMaskIndex = 0;

            byte[] byteKeys = BitConverter.GetBytes(maskingKey);
            for (int index = 0; index < payload.Length; ++index)
            {
                payload[index] = (byte)(payload[index] ^ byteKeys[currentMaskIndex]);
                currentMaskIndex = (++currentMaskIndex)%4;
            }
        }
```

`frame.UnmaskedPayload`: this contains the full bytes of the message and I try to convert those bytes back to image.

But it gives the exception that its not valid parameter data.

Comment: It may be worth if you put the code that converts the bytes in an actual image

Comment: When i try to convert into image it gives me error that parameter is not valid.  My be my data is not properly convert into the image bytes.

Comment: that is way you should put the code. I do not see a reason to convert to base64string

Comment: No body respond to my thread. I need urgently please any body add some lights on this issue/